# Recursively using implicit methods in Scala

Tags: scala, implicit, implicit-methods

I'd like to define some implicit methods for arrays of doubles to make my code cleaner.  Ideally, they would look like this:

```
type Vec = Array[Double]

implicit def enrichVec(v: Vec) = new {
  def /(x: Double) = v map (_/x)
  def *(u: Vec) = (v zip u) map {case (x,y) => x*y} sum
  def normalize = v / math.sqrt(v * v)
}
```

However the `normalize` function doesn't work as written because Scala won't apply implicit methods recursively.  Specifically, I get an error `Note: implicit method enrichVec is not applicable here because it comes after the application point and it lacks an explicit result type`. I could avoid this by explicitly writing out the code for `normalize`, but that would be ugly.  Is there a nicer solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The anonymous class inhibits the recursive function definitions. You need to define the "RichVec" as a class and then separately define the implicit conversion.

```
type Vec = Array[Double]
implicit def enrichVec(v: Vec) = RichVec( v )
case class RichVec( v: Vec ) {
  def /(x: Double) = v map (_/x)
  def *(u: Vec) = (v zip u) map {case (x,y) => x*y} sum
  def normalize = v / math.sqrt( v * v )
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile (am trying with Scala 2.9.0-1): `error: value / is not a member of Vec`

Comment: Ironically the    v / math.sqrt( v * v )   works if you move the implicit above the case class

Comment: Any particular reason you used `case class` here instead of just `class`?

Comment: RichVec( v ) == RichVec( v ) holds true for case classes. However it is not a complete RichVec and equals would have to be redefined anyway making the use of case class useless for that purpose.

Comment: To sum up that last comment. No, not based on a complete thought anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
type Vec = Array[Double]
abstract class RichVec(v: Vec) {
  def /(x: Double): Vec
  def *(u: Vec): Double
  def normalize: Vec
}
implicit def enrichVec(v: Vec): RichVec = new RichVec( v ) {
  def /(x: Double) = v map (_/x)
  def *(u: Vec) = (v zip u) map {case (x,y) => x*y} sum
  def normalize = v / math.sqrt(v * v)
}
```

But there are other ways to do it. What is most important is that you *specify the return type* for the implicit.